# Centering an image - works only with an auxiliary div

Tags: html, css

I have a div and I want to add a logo in its middle. If I write:

```
<div id="header">
    <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png" title="Logo" />
</div>
#logo {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 278px;
}
```

Nothing happens.
But if I make a special div for the image, like this:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id = "logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" title="Logo" />
    </div>
</div>
 #logo {
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 278px;
 }
```

It works, and the image is centered. Why?

Comment: Try adding `display: block` to the first CSS block.

Answer (score 4):

Images are inline by default, so they won't respect that `margin: auto` off the bat. What you can do (without the extra div) is give `text-align: center` to the #header.

The reason the auxiliary div works is because you are wrapping the image in a div with the same dimensions, and being a block element, the div will respect margin auto and center itself.

Answer (score 0):

[this post](http://www.netmechanic.com/news/vol7/html_no10.htm) may give you some help

It explains to you why you need wrap a div and how to do it without a div wrapper(but may have browser compatible issue)